# How to define an array of a type in an external file in Raml?

Tags: arrays, types, include, modularity, raml

If I have a file defining a Datatype `SimpleDuple`, and in another file defining another datatype called `DiscreetFilter` I want to have a property `values` to be an array of `SimpleDuple` how would I use include there?

Consider the files for SimpleDuple:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  id: string
  name: string
```

And the other definition where I want to make a property be an array of SimpleDuples in the `values` property (but I had to use an inline definition).

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  field: string
  name: string
  type: { enum: [ discreet ] }

  # Ideally this property would use an include
  # in some way to express the equivalent of SimpleDuple[]
  values: 
    type: array
    properties:
      id: string
      name: string
```

If those two types where on the same file I'd set the `values` property to  `SimpleDuple[]`. If it wasn't an array I'd put the include as the value of the `values` property.

But how do I use an include and an array at the same time instead of using the inline definition I used in the copied code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

**chapter.raml**

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  name: string
```

**storyboard.raml**

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
properties:
  name: string
  chapters:
    type: array
    items: !include chapter.raml
```

Hope that helps?!