# How to override an object array property type in RAML 1.0

Tags: java, generics, raml

I have a generic Java type like this:

```
class Response<D> {
  List<D> data;
}
```

and want to create something similar with RAML 1.0 (where I am new to).

My first approach was

```
types:
  Response:
    type: object
    properties:
      data: object[]
```

and when using it

```
body:
  type: Response
    properties:
      data: MyDataType[]
```

From API-Workbench I always get an "Illegal override of property data inherited from Response".

The other idea would be to use `repeat`:

```
types:
  Response:
    type: object
    properties:
      data: object
      repeat: true
```

and respectively

```
body:
  type: Response
    properties:
      data: MyDataType
      repeat: true
```

Now the illegal override is gone but in the API-Console I now get an "Uncaught TypeError".

How to solve that? Or do I need a completely different approach? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, `Response` is abstracting different types of data, but has similar format. One approach is to abstract the similarity in the response using `resourceTypes` and define your concrete data in `types`.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: New API
version: v1
baseUri: http://api.samplehost.com
mediaType: application/json

types:
  User:
    usage: A user in the system    
    properties:
      firstname:
        required: true
      lastname:
        required: true

  ArticleId:
    usage: An id of any article in the system
    type: number

  Article:
    usage: Pattern for any article in the system
    properties:
      id:
        type: ArticleId
        required: true
      created:
        type: date
        required: true

#######################################
# the following captures the similarity:
#######################################

resourceTypes:
  collection:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            properties:
              data: <<typename>>[]


###############
# API:
############### 

/user:
  description: All the users
  type:
    collection:
      typename: User

/article:
  description: All the articles
  type:
    collection:
      typename: Article
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the following options in solving this issue:

1. Screen open source repositories for testcases, which hopefully document your requirements. I found this project [raml-java-parser tests](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-java-parser/tree/master/src/test/java/org/raml/parser) with a load of testcases but couldn't find the solution on the first try.
   Here is a specific testcase resource containing the string [collectionSchema in double angle brackets (from raml-for-jaxrs)](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/raml-to-jaxrs/core/src/test/resources/org/raml/integration/sales-enablement-api-with-collections.yaml#L87) syntax, looks suspicous?
2. Use an API to produce a serialized version of the expected input e.g. your `List<MyDataType>`, and revise the generated output. E.g. using the same raml-java-parser from point 1.
3. Find a reference for the whole file specification, including complex types. Seems as [this](http://docs.raml.org/specs/1.0/#type-expressions) and [this](http://docs.raml.org/specs/1.0/#raml-10-spec-types) could include the interesting information, like "map/dictionary with `type{}` or the fact that exterior types might need an inclusion. Maybe [this answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887678/3165552) helps on this behalf.
4. The raml tag on your question is currently followed by only 37 users. Are there more general tags possible, in order target a broader audience?

I didn't knew anything about RAML 20 minutes ago, so don't treat this as a complete answer but a quick guess.

Answer (score 0):

You said "and when using it":
body:
  type: Response
    properties:
      data: MyDataType[]

You already defined the "Response" type above to have a "data" property as "object[]".  Where did "MyDataType" come from?  Just remove "properties" here and just have "type: Response.  Then the error should go away.
Perhaps you are wanting your Response type to have "any[]".  I cannot tell what you are trying to do.  Maybe define another type which inherits your Response type.

Comment: Maybe you missed the Java type declaration and the mentioned generic in the question but `any` would remove the error but document nothing, which is not the intention of using a endpoint documentation tool.