# How to define a union of a type in an external file in Raml datatype fragment?

Tags: types, nested, raml, union-types

First, this question is similar to, but different from [How to define an array of a type in an external file in Raml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886455/how-to-define-an-array-of-a-type-in-an-external-file-in-raml/34887678#34887678), except I want to make a DataType (A) that has a property that is a union of two other DataTypes B and C.

For example, here is the B RAML:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
   some: integer
```

Here is the C RAML:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  other: string
```

And finally here is the problematic A RAML:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
   union: !include B | !include C
```

In the solution to the aforementioned post, the A RAML would have something like:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
    type: object
    properties:
       union: 
          type: union
          items: !include B | !include C
```

But that doesn't work either. Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. It is to use Library instead of DataType fragments. You can nest library references inside library definitions.

So, you can have a Library fragment in which B is defined, another in which C is defined, and then another in which A is defined as a union of B and C. Problem solved.

Here is a link to the article that spells out libraries and fragments: https://medium.com/raml-api/raml-101-libraries-and-datatypes-fragments-1889b2e82c27

Full creds goes to an anonymous hellper inside Mulesoft that pointed me to the article. Thanks, you know who you are.